# How to convert char* to jcharArray in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

How can I convert char* to jcharArray in JNI?

What code do I have to put in // TODO comment part?

```
JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL Java_finger_FingerPrintJNI_GetVer(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj){
    char* version = getText(); // Returns char* data type
    int version_len = strlen(version);

    jcharArray j_version_array = env->NewCharArray(version_len + 1);

    // TODO Convert char* to jcharArray

    return jcharArray;
}
```

Add ======================================================================

As Gearon suggested, when I put the below code an error is raised.

```
jchar* jVersion = (jchar*)version;
env->SetCharArrayRegion(jcharArray, 0, version_len, jVersion);
```

Following is the error message.

```
JNIEnv_::SetCharArrayRegion(jcharArray,jsize,jsize,const jchar *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'jchar *' to 'jcharArray'
sample.cpp(26): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Anderson, check my update please. I'm sorry that I did a typo just now. Replace jcharArray with j_version_array and it's what to be assigned.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the code Gearon suggested my final code is something like this.

```
jchar* j_version = (jchar*)calloc(sizeof(jchar), version_len);
for(int i=0; i <= version_len; i++){
    j_version[i] =  (jchar) version[i];
}

jcharArray j_version_array = env->NewCharArray(version_len + 1);
env->SetCharArrayRegion(j_version_array, 0, version_len , j_version);
```

Comment: What is the `+1` for in `NewCharArray`?

Comment: I'm guessing its to all the char array to be null terminated.

Comment: This is the best way.

Comment: CharArray-s are sized, in the regular without need of a 0-termination

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
jchar* jVersion = (jchar*)version;
env->SetCharArrayRegion(j_version_array, 0, version_len, jVersion);
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks.

Comment: The above code results in an error. 

    JNIEnv_::SetCharArrayRegion(jcharArray,jsize,jsize,const jchar *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'jchar *' to 'jcharArray'
    sample.cpp(26): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: the above code runs well in compile. But when I get the string in JAVA I got something like this. 
"[穩, 楺, 䙸, 䥃, 䥟, 䵍, 㐶, 瑳, ⁤, 㑖, 㐮, ‰, 䥈, 匭, 䕐, 䑅, 䰠, 䵉, 呉, 䑅,  ,  ,  , 㽀, 剅, 佒, ⁒, ›, 污, 潬, 晣, 瑥, 牟, 瑥, 㨠, 挠, 污, 潬, ⁣, ›,  ]"

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it. But maybe you can check the encode rule in both java side and native side. Another possibility, make sure the version pointer itself point to a meaningful memory area.