# How to retrieve user input value and store it to jchar array in C (JNI)?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

Expected OutPut

[image]

- I want to create an Jchar array, the size of the array is base on user input size.
- How to store input value to the jchar array?
- For example the first input is 'A' and the second is 'S'.
- I want to store value 'A' to array[0] and 'S' to array[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AwPG.png)].
- based on code below, i'm unable to store the value to jchar array.

  **Code:**

```
JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL Java_array_getArrayCharacter(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){       
    int i, size;
    jchar array[size];
    //array size
    printf("Enter Size of Array : ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    //User input Character
    printf("\n--User Defined Character--\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Input %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%hc", &array[i]);
    }

    //Display array
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%hc\n", array[i]);
    }

    //create new array with the given length
    jcharArray result = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, size);

    // update the new created array result
    (*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, result, 0, size, array);

    return result;      
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, but one of the errors of the above code is that you should pass arguments to scanf by pointer: `scanf("%c", &array[i]);`.

Comment: Note that `jchar` is a 16-bit type ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)), which is probably larger than a `char`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert char\* to jcharArray in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493156/how-to-convert-char-to-jchararray-in-jni)

Comment: Don't add `[Solved]` or such to titles. Instead, accept an answer, post one yourself, flag it as a duplicate, or delete it. Still-open questions without posted answers clog up the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to revolve around this ...

> ```
>     for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>         printf("Input %d: ",i+1);
>         scanf("%hc", &array[i]);
>     }
> ```

... and maybe this, too:

> ```
>     //Display array
>     for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
>         printf("%hc\n", array[i]);
>     }
> ```

The main problem with these from a C-language perspective is that the `h` modifier character is not applicable to `%c` fields.  But you seem to be struggling more generally with the difference between Java `char` and C `char`.  The former is a 16-bit, unsigned data type, most often interpreted as containing a UTF-16 code unit.  The latter is an 8-or-more-bit (but probably 8), maybe-signed data type, whose mapping to abstract characters is (C-)implementation dependent.

If we can make the simplifying assumptions that

1. your C implementation uses an ASCII-compatible runtime character encoding (UTF-8, Windows 1252, or any of the ISO 8859 family, among others), and
2. you do not need to support characters outside (7-bit) ASCII's range

then the answer is relatively simple.  You read data as type (C) `char`, and you convert back and forth between that and `jchar` by implicit conversion or cast.  For example,

```
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char c;
        printf("Input %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%c", &c);
        array[i] = c;                     // implicit conversion across the assignment
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%c\n", (char) array[i]);  // explicit conversion via cast
    }
```

*Note: that probably will correctly echo the input (C) characters to the output even if neither assumption holds.*

If either of the above assumptions does not hold, however, then you'll need to deal with character encoding issues in order for Java to interpret the char array as containing the same characters that C interprets its input to represent.  You would then want to read the input into a `jbyte` array, and perform the appropriate conversion to char array via one of the applicable Java methods, based on the actual encoding of the input, such as via a [CharsetDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).  You can, of course, do that even if both assumptions do hold, too.